# How to to use one instance of mysql database in a dual boot setup

Tags: mysql

I have a duel boot machine having Windows and Ubuntu 12.10.

I was using MySQL database in my Windows machine and now want to use it form Ubuntu. I installed mysql in Ubuntu and set `datadir`.

As mentioned in this Post, I changed **/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld** also.

Still when I run the command

`sudo service mysql start`, I'm getting the error **start: Job failed to start**

The command `dmesg | grep mysql` is showing the output.

```
> [ 9766.942099] type=1400 audit(1362299426.097:88): apparmor="STATUS"
> operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=6097
> comm="apparmor_parser" [ 9766.953873] init: mysql main process (6101)
> terminated with status 1 [ 9766.953895] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [ 9766.957071] init: mysql post-start process (6102)
> terminated with status 1 [ 9766.963364] type=1400
> audit(1362299426.117:89): apparmor="STATUS"
> operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=6117
> comm="apparmor_parser" [ 9766.974864] init: mysql main process (6121)
> terminated with status 1 [ 9766.974883] init: mysql main process
> ended, respawning [ 9767.979418] init: mysql post-start process (6122)
> terminated with status 1 [ 9767.987662] type=1400
> audit(1362299427.145:90): apparmor="STATUS"
> operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=6145
> comm="apparmor_parser" [ 9768.003272] init: mysql main process (6149)
> terminated with status 1 [ 9768.003291] init: mysql respawning too
> fast, stopped
```

How can I use the existing data file  in Ubuntu? Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqldump for backuping database from windows and install it in ubuntu. For gui you can use export/import option in phpmyadmin

Comment: That means I've to maintain two instances of database? export/import will take care of only new data updates?

Comment: Do you want to share same instance of db for both os?

Comment: Yes. I want to use the same database file in both os. In worst case only I would like to prefer the `mysqldump` option.